# How can you display GLatLng as text on screen with google maps?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to display the central coordinates of the displayed map in a floating div on the screen. Ideally, updating as the map is moved around.

I have found the GLatLng class: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference?csw=1#GLatLng

How do I get that data and display it on screen? Or is this even the right way to do this?

Comment: Your [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference?csw=1#GLatLng) is to the Google Maps Javascript API v2 which was officially deprecated on May 19, 2010.  Use [v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) instead

Comment: Yeah. Stupid of me not to realise. I'm also seeing that map.getCentre() might be the way to go